# how to access dashboard of wordpress.com blog for new user

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a new user for `wordpress.com` blog. When I try to access dashboard it appeared to be like this:

[image]

But the real dashboard would look like this:

[image]

I'd like to know how to go from the page shown in the 1st image to the page shown in the 2nd image step by step.

I've tried to play around but still cannot figure it out how to go from the 1st image to the 2nd image.

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose you have a wordpress site whose domain is like this

```
www.mynewsite.wordpress.com
```

then you can access admin's dashboard by adding `/wp-admin` at the end. So it will be like

```
www.mynewsite.wordpress.com/wp-admin
```

Then enter your admin username/email and password to login into the dashboard.

If you have purchased a domain and setup a wordpress on it then, Similarly it will be `www.yourdomain.com/wp-admin`

**2nd Option:**

According to your screenshot, You will find an option to login into your wordpress admin dashboard by scrolling down and clicking on `WP Admin` button. Screenshot of it is attached below. It will also redirect you to same page.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. That means that there's no specific button to click on it to access the admin's dashboard. It can only be accessed by adding some more characters: /wp-admin, right ?

Comment: Yeah There is no button, you only have the Url to access by adding `/wp-admin` at the end of the url.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm a new user and thus have no idea about adding the ''/wp-admin''

Comment: This youtube video shows several ways to access dashboard: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-MF-epBurAE&t=65s] but somehow I cannot follow the other ways that the video instructs. What seems to be the issue here?

Comment: Its because maybe if you have multiple sites but check my updated answer i have added an option 2, from which you can easily go to that dashboard of each site that u have. @Laurentz

Comment: Thanks your the additional information, but after scrolling down, the bar of my blog does not have WP-admin section. Its image here: https://postimg.org/image/r024ssxvd/

Comment: Then it maybe because of not complete installation, try reinstalling wp again.